# Want to change UIView background color with time of day

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Pretty simple, I just want to change my `backgroundView`'s color depending on the time of day, but for some reason it doesn't work. Any help would be great.

```
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let darkColor=UIColor(red: 51, green: 52, blue: 50, alpha: 1.0)
    let greyColor=UIColor(red: 238, green: 240, blue: 239, alpha: 1.0)
    let hour = NSCalendar.current.component(.hour, from: NSDate() as Date)

    switch hour {
        case 1..<6: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor
           break
        case 7..<18: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = greyColor
           break
        case 19..<24: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor
           break
    default:self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = greyColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you linked backgroundView to the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah I just double checked and it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the following lines are ignoring 6, 18, 24, respectively:

```
1..<6 //1 - 5

7..<18 //7 - 17

19..<24 //19 - 23
```

Depending on the time you had, when you checked it; if it happened to fall on either 6, 18, 24, then it could be the reason why you thought it is not working.

Using your code, I confirmed that the `backgroundColor` of the view does change.

Try changing the code to the following:

```
switch hour
{
     // hours 1 to 6
     case 1...6: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor
            break
     // hours 7 to 18
     case 7...18: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = greyColor
            break
     //hours 19 to 23 and 0
     case 19...23, 0: self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor
            break
     default:self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = greyColor
}
```

Another problem is the following:

```
let darkColor=UIColor(red: 51, green: 52, blue: 50, alpha: 1.0)

let greyColor=UIColor(red: 238, green: 240, blue: 239, alpha: 1.0)
```

as they should be:

```
let darkColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 52/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1.0)

let greyColor = UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 240/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer works perfectly! Another thank you for saving me from the future hassle of finding out why there isn't a change occurring on "6, 18, 24 "

Answer (score 1):

While running your app, you may have gotten a console log message in Xcode that says something like:

> [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the
>   expected range. Set a breakpoint on
>   UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will
>   only be logged once.

The `UIColor` `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)` initializer expects a value between `0.0` and `1.0`. In order to translate a RGB value that is within `0-255` to a value between `0.0` to `1.0`, you need to divide your desired color intensity by `255`.

Try changing your color declarations from:

```
let darkColor = UIColor(red: 51, green: 52, blue: 50, alpha: 1.0)

let greyColor = UIColor(red: 238, green: 240, blue: 239, alpha: 1.0)
```

to

```
let darkColor = UIColor(red: 51/255.0, green: 52/255.0, blue: 50/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

let greyColor = UIColor(red: 238/255.0, green: 240/255.0, blue: 239/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

**EDIT:**

@Unheilig answer makes a good point about your switch logic for the `hour`. However if this **is** intentional, then your default case would catch hours `0`, `6`, `18` and `24` and your background color would be `greyColor`.